# Transfer tokens after smart contract is deployed

Tags: contract-deployment

When the smart contact will be deployed, I want to send some tokens to another wallet, by smart contract. 
 
 
Is there some way to do that?

Comment: can you put your SC address here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract Demo {

    uint public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 1000000000;
    mapping (address => uint) public balances;

    function Demo() public {
        balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY - 1000;
        balances[address(0)] = 1000;
    }

}
```

Replace `address(0)` with some real address which you want to send your tokens

or you can pass address on contract deployment:

```
function Demo(address _address) public {
    balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY - 1000;
    balances[_address] = 1000;
}
```

Comment: I get an issue. I try this way but again get "Warning: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum"

Comment: balanceOf[0x14723a09acff6d2a60dcdf7aa4aff308fddc160c] = 140000000;

Comment: @ArikDonowan [Solidity: How to specify a (hard-coded) address as a literal](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17060/solidity-how-to-specify-a-hard-coded-address-as-a-literal)