# Solidity. How to add an address to a mapping

Tags: solidity, addresses, mapping

I have this:

```
contract Diary {
    string[] private facts;
    mapping (address => bool) approvedAddresses;
    address owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        approvedAddresses[0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c] = true;
    }
```

I get this error:

> SyntaxError: This looks like an address but has an invalid checksum.
>   Correct checksummed address:
>   "0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c". If this is not used as
>   an address..

Which is the correct way to do this? I'm new to solidity..

Comment: Solidity doesn't like addresses that aren't in their proper checksummed form. Just use the checksummed version of the address that they gave you: `0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message gives you both the reason for error (incorrect checksum) and the way to fix the error (the letters in your address must be uppercase).
Just copy paste the address provided by the error message in your code.
See [this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17060/solidity-how-to-specify-a-hard-coded-address-as-a-literal).